# python is not responding

Tags: python, pygame

This is a simple game code
I run it, "python is not responding" come up. When I put on all about "computer", "player", it began
please help me        [python is not responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2brl4.png)
this is my code:

```
import pygame
from random import randint
def draw_floor():
    screen.blit(floor, (floorrunning, 453))
    screen.blit(floor, (floorrunning + 800, 453))
                
pygame.init()
bg = pygame.image.load("background.png")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500))

GREY = (120, 120, 120)
WHITE = (255, 25, 255)

floor = pygame.image.load("quangcaobanthan.png")
floorrunning = 0

xucxac1 = pygame.image.load("nan1.png")
xucxac2 = pygame.image.load("nan1_2.png")
xucxac3 = pygame.image.load("nan1_3.png")
xucxac1_rect = (141, 300)
xucxac2_rect = (341, 300)
xucxac3_rect = (541, 300)

running = True
replay = True

ketqua1 = randint(1,6)
ketqua2 = randint(1,6)
ketqua3 = randint(1,6)
computer = ketqua1 + ketqua2 + ketqua3
player = input()

game_font = pygame.font.SysFont("04B_19.ttf", 40)
def ketqua():
    ketqua1_infor = game_font.render(str(ketqua1), True, (0,0,0))
    ketqua1_rect = (190, 334)
    screen.blit(ketqua1_infor, ketqua1_rect)
    ketqua2_infor = game_font.render(str(ketqua2), True, (0,0,0))
    ketqua2_rect = (390, 334)
    screen.blit(ketqua2_infor, ketqua2_rect)
    ketqua3_infor = game_font.render(str(ketqua3), True, (0,0,0))
    ketqua3_rect = (590, 334)
    screen.blit(ketqua3_infor, ketqua3_rect)
```

thank alls

Comment: Your Operating System expects your pygame window to handle events, or it will report that the window is not responding. When you call the `input()` function, your code execution is blocked until the enter key is pressed in the console window. If you want a player to enter a string, you'll need to handle the keyboard events to accumulate the username.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()`.
Also, you need

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
```

So change your code to

```
import pygame
from random import randint
def draw_floor():
    screen.blit(floor, (floorrunning, 453))
    screen.blit(floor, (floorrunning + 800, 453))
                
pygame.init()
bg = pygame.image.load("background.png")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500))

GREY = (120, 120, 120)
WHITE = (255, 25, 255)

floor = pygame.image.load("quangcaobanthan.png")
floorrunning = 0

xucxac1 = pygame.image.load("nan1.png")
xucxac2 = pygame.image.load("nan1_2.png")
xucxac3 = pygame.image.load("nan1_3.png")
xucxac1_rect = (141, 300)
xucxac2_rect = (341, 300)
xucxac3_rect = (541, 300)

running = True
replay = True

ketqua1 = randint(1,6)
ketqua2 = randint(1,6)
ketqua3 = randint(1,6)
computer = ketqua1 + ketqua2 + ketqua3
#player = input() this is also stopping your code

game_font = pygame.font.SysFont("04B_19.ttf", 40)
def ketqua():
    ketqua1_infor = game_font.render(str(ketqua1), True, (0,0,0))
    ketqua1_rect = (190, 334)
    screen.blit(ketqua1_infor, ketqua1_rect)
    ketqua2_infor = game_font.render(str(ketqua2), True, (0,0,0))
    ketqua2_rect = (390, 334)
    screen.blit(ketqua2_infor, ketqua2_rect)
    ketqua3_infor = game_font.render(str(ketqua3), True, (0,0,0))
    ketqua3_rect = (590, 334)
    screen.blit(ketqua3_infor, ketqua3_rect)
while running:
    draw_floor()
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Comment: Please see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-text-input-box-with-pygame/ for information on how to create an input box in pygame